# how do I fix library mismatch error with wxWidgets

Tags: compiling

Ok so I'm trying to run  this  program I've installed the dependancies wxWidgets and GLUT. 
however everytime I try to run it I recieve this error

Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.
The library used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.6),
and your program used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.4,compatible with 2.6).
Aborted (core dumped)

from what I've learned I need to recompile wxWidgets, but I have no idea how to do that and I am having a hard time finding useful information out there on the interwebs. 
So any help would be greatly appreciated!

ubuntu Version 14.04.4

packages installed: libwxgtk2.8-dev libwxgtk2.8-dbg freeglut3 freeglut3-dev   installed via apt-get

software: http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~ahg/MIPS-Datapath/

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, and what wxWidgets / GLUT packages did you install exactly (and how)? What is the program, and where did you get it? if the source code is available, it might be easier to recompile the program to use the available library versions, rather then the other way around.

Comment: yes it would seem the source code is available how would I recompile it?